# HttpClient - add CipherInputStream to MultipartEntity

Tags: java, encryption, file-upload, file-io, multipartentity

I want to add an encripted stream to my multipartentity to upload it to my servlet but I don't know how to do that... Emm then MultipartEntity is quite limited as for addPart(...,...) method params.
I found no examples in that area so I need your help.
Please share any useful snippets and ideas.

Any comment is appreciated.

Andrew

P.S. I am using HttpClient 4

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to encapsulate the CipherInputStream into a [`org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/InputStreamBody.html)?

Afterwards you can encapsulate it in an [`org.apache.http.entity.mime.FormBodyPart`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart.html) which can be added via `addBodyPart()` to your [`HttpMultipart`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/HttpMultipart.html) instance.

Comment: No I haven't tried to encapsulate because I suppose to upload big files which demand buffer reading no to have the outOfMemory error...

Comment: The problem is that the addPart() demands FileInputStream as a param but the CipherInputStream encrypted result is FileOutputStream :(

Comment: Moreover, if file is big it takes too much time to
"encrypt" then "upload" :( Both demand time so I guess there should be a way around?

Comment: Please read exactly what I have read. I was taking about the method `addBodyPart()` not `addPart()` - therefore I assume we are talking about different classes. This happened because you did not include the code you are using.